# Swift overriding extension method

Tags: swift

I am looking a way to override base class extension method in subclass. As per my knowledge swift doesn't allow to do this directly. This method is protocol method. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
protocol Creator {
    func create()
}
class BaseClass {

}

extension BaseClass: Creator {

    func create() {
        print("create")
    }
}

class Subclass1: BaseClass {
    // override create method
    // add own implementation of create()
}

class Subclass2 : BaseClass {
    // override create method
    // add own implementation of create()
}

let subclass1 = Subclass1().create() // execute create from Subclass1
let subclass2 = Subclass2().create() // execute create from Subclass2
```

Comment: Error says: "Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet." Quite helpful really.

Comment: Another way would be _you could provide default implementation in a protocol extension_ not in the class extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the declaration of `create` into the actual class declaration. Everything else can stay the same:

```
protocol Creator {
    func create()
}
class BaseClass {
    func create() {
        print("create")
    }
}
extension BaseClass: Creator {
}
// and so on
```

The effect is precisely the same, but now `override func create()` is legal in your subclasses.

Comment: thank. is there any other way? I want to keep all Creator methods grouped together in extension only.

Comment: I know you do, and I prefer that style too, but in this situation you cannot ("yet", as the error message says). At least be happy that you can conform to Creator without having to put the required methods in the extension that declares adoption: that was not always true.